# How can I delete a user from my mongoose and node web app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I have so far got an app where users can register and sign in. I have also implicated a role based system, However I am struggling when it comes to deleting a user. I have looked all over the web but nothing seems to work. I think my delete route is fine, but when I click the delete button nothing happens. I have identified the user id in the url but it doesn't delete. Any help would be much appreciated.

in routes/admin.js

```
//Delete a user
router.delete('/delete/:id', (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    User.findByIdAndDelete({_id: req.params.id});
  // res.redirect('/admin');
  } catch (error) {
    res.redirect('/index');
  }
});
```

in views/manage-users.ejs

```
<form action="/admin/delete/:<%= user.id %>" method="delete">
          <button type="submit">DELETE</button>
      </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this.

```
router.delete("/delete/:id",  (req: Request, res: Response) => {
      const id = req.params.id;
    
    
      Links.deleteOne({ _id: id })
        .then((data) =>
          res.json({
            data: data,
          })
        )
        .catch((error) => {
          return res.send(error);
        });
    });
```

Comment: I still get this as my url localhost:3000/admin/delete/628644263531b5f30478539c?, also is my ejs correct format, to call the right route?

Comment: Ya your ejs code is correct also you're getting an ID "628644263531b5f30478539c"  so, you can use it that id to delete user from MongoDB

Comment: when I click the button it redirects me to the url with the correct id , but it doesnt delete it from the db